# Why is my compiler stuck in Octal?

Tags: c++, iostream

I wrote a program experimenting with dec, hex, and oct, output and input.
Then I erased it all, and wrote this code in the same project. The compiler keeps giving me an
error for the phone in main(), saying invalid Octal digits. So I copied the code into Notepad++, then restarted and created a new projected in MS visual C++ 2010, and pasted the code back into it, and it's still giving me the error. What could the problem be???

```
 //main.cpp******************************************************************************
#include "lib.h"

struct table
{
    table(string firstName, string lastName, long int phone, string email)
        :firstName(firstName), lastName(lastName), phone(phone), email(email)
    {}

string firstName;
string lastName;
long int phone;
string email;
};


//****************************************************************************


int main()
{

vector<table> details;

cout<<dec;//I thought maybe this would convert back to dec

details.push_back(table("bill","bryson",05289994590, 
    "billb0998@gmail.com"));

    keep_window_open();

}

//******************************************************************************
```

Comment: If that's someone's actual contact details, you might want to edit that out of your question.

Answer (score 5):

The literal `05289994590` is an octal literal, because of the leading `0`. If you want a decimal literal, spell it as `5289994590`, though phone numbers should probably be stored in some other form, e.g. strings.

That has nothing to do with the iostream library formatting. Rather, this is part of the C++ grammar.

Comment: I would further add that storing phone "numbers" as actual numeric types is a path to madness.

Comment: @JoeZ: Yeah, I was thinking that too.

Comment: Especially since the first character of an international phone number is `+` ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'd say that's part of the representation. Some native E.164 type is probably called for, with a rich I/O interface.